# MYSQL doesn't check for Foreign key exsistence

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am facing a strange problem here.

TABLE 1:

```
create table degree (degree_id varchar(6) primary key , degree_name varchar(32) unique key , degree_abbr varchar(3));
```

TABLE 2:

```
create table course (course_id varchar(6) primary key , degree_id varchar(6) not null, course_name varchar(40) not null ,  foreign key (degree_id) references degree 
(degree_id));
```

Now as far as I understand SQL , I cannot insert any value in the course table if the value of field degree_id doesn't exist in the degree table.

But if I try to insert something like

```
insert into course values('cor_001' , 'blah' , 'COURSE NAME' );
```

This query runs successfully , even though 'blah' is not a valid degree_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using MyISAM tables, which do NOT support foreign keys. The FK directives are parsed and accepted, then ignored.

You need to use InnoDB tables for proper FK support:

```
CREATE TABLE (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you do a `show create table your_table`, you'll see the engine type being used at the end of the output.

Comment: Yes , That's correct. Now how do I change them to use InnoDB ? I already have a lot of tables created and populated. I cannot effort to drop my tables.

Comment: `alter table yourtable engine=innodb`. You will have to further alter the table to re-apply the FK definitions. They are lost once myisam's finished with the `create` queries.

Comment: K. So I need to first alter all the engine and then alter the table to apply the foreign keys. Is there anyway to change the default engine of mysql? so that I don't need to mention the ENGINE attribute everytime I create a table?

Comment: `default-storage-engine` in my.cnf/my.ini